# Transfer files between two NAS units on same network

Tags: networking, ftp, network-shares, nas

I have two [Seagate BlackArmor 400](http://www.seagate.com/gb/en/external-hard-drives/network-storage/business/blackarmor-nas-400/) NAS units and I want to transfer a lot of files from one to the other.

I can access both through a browser GUI and also are the shares I want to transfer between available in my Network Location in Windows 7. I guess that's the CIFS thing there but not sure.

However if I just drag and drop or use something like TeraCopy the speed is very bad. It's like the file actually transfers through my PC which is wireless and not getting great speed.

The Seagate blackarmor has a download manager that supports http and ftp and the share is ftp enabled but I have no idea how it's url would be on local network ( there is no DNS setup for the FTP but it's marked as enabled ).

Does anyone know of a good solution for me to transfer the files between the 2 NAS system without having a PC in between and getting good speed.

Comment: If you need to copy **now** then try again with a wired network cable. That will significantly increase the speed. But the optimal solution would be to log in on one of the NAS units and copy from there.

Comment: As both the NAS units have FTP, you could test and see if [FXP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol) is enabled, which would allow for direct file transfers.  If FTP is enabled, I'd imagine just pointing an FTP (or FXP) client at the IP address for the NAS will get you an FTP connection . . .

Comment: Foe full disclosure I tried to just move it over network through a PC but it was very unstable, connection lost issues. So my solution was FTP from NAS to PC, and the from PC to other NAS in chunks. When I wired the computer to the network I was able to get speeds in excess of 10mb/sec when transferring multiple files at once. This was acceptable solution while not the best. It seems that the Blackarmor also has a Backup manager that can backup to another NAS but I never tried that out.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your assumption that the files are being copied *to* your machine and then back to the 2nd NAS.

The only way to accomplish this is if there is a way to setup some sort of direct file-exchange between the two NAS devices.  Either some sort of command-line tool for pushing or pulling the files from the other NAS.  If there is no command line tool, perhaps there is a GUI tool like `RSYNC` that can be configured to pull data from a remote server.  There might also be some options for some other replication tools that might be useful.

Comment: I do not believe a command line tool was included and SSH is not a possibility. I was hoping perhaps for the FTP solution but I have no idea what the ftp address would be on a LAN ftp server.

Comment: FTP would do the same thing as a network share.  The problem is, most file-transfer protocols out there are strictly client->server.  There typically is no concept of server->server or peer->peer or a way to negotiate a file transfer in 99% of the common file-transfer protocols.

Comment: [FXP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol) will do server to server, if the FTP servers support it . . .

Comment: @ernie: good suggestion, but that fits in to the phrasing I used... (most/typically/99%/common).  Unfortunately, most NAS appliances have the most stripped-down packages they can find.  I would seriously doubt they would have support for FXP.  It's worth a try tho :)

Comment: Yeah I tried to use FlashFXP to transfer between but got some error so I guess FXP isn't supported. I guess it will have to be a slow and boring 2mb/sec transfer.

Answer (score 1):

For the cheap NAS devices like the ones you mentioned, you are limited to what you are doing already, i.e., a host based copy and yes it will be painfully slow.

If you are not the faint of the heart tye of person, who don't mind cracking open the plastic device enclosures, and if the data on your target drive is not that important or small enough to be stashed somewhere else, I'd suggest asking people you know if they have a disc cloning machine that you can borrow or use and take your drives to this machine, clone them. Then delete the portions which are no interest to you after you are done and pout the drives back into their enclosures.

Short of that, I'd suggest, dividing the data you want to copy into manageable chunks and start copying few chunks before you go to bed every night and let the computer do your job for you as you sleep.

Answer (score 0):

This post has 22k views, so it is clearly of interest to many people despite being old, and doesn't have a good solution posted.

It depends on the NAS system used, but if it is able to mount remote locations/map network drives, then this can be a way to avoid transferring from server-laptop-server, and going direct server-server. Let's say you have Server A (with your files) and Server B (where you want to copy them to).

In Synology devices, access Server B through the browser interface, open File Station, go to Tools, then Mount Remote Folder, then CIFS Shared Folder. Enter the address of Server A (which you can find through the browser interface of Server A, then Networking) and the share folder address.

Then in Server B browser interface, you can drag and drop, then Copy the files from the mounted remote folder to a local folder on Server B. This will use the wired LAN connection and be much faster than going through an intermediate device.

Some more detailed steps outlined here: https://florianjensen.com/2019/08/19/apc-bx950u-gr-ups-on-synology/